# Powershell 3.0 : Alternative to "Get-Volume"

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to get various properties for each hdd-volume on the computer.

I was using the cmdlet `get-volume` and then walking through it via `foreach`, but that cmdlet does not exist in Windows Server 2008. :(

Does anybody know an alternative?

I just need the drive letter, objectId/guid, free space, total space, and the name of each volume.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The WMI class Win32_Volume has the information you are looking for

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Volume | Select DriveLetter,FreeSpace,Capacity,DeviceID,Label
```

Which a little fancy footwork you can make the drive space properties looking a little more appealing.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume | 
        Select DriveLetter,
            @{Label="FreeSpace (In GB)";Expression={$_.Freespace/1gb}},
            @{Label="Capacity (In GB)";Expression={$_.Capacity/1gb}},
            DeviceID,Label |
        Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 1):

Get-Volume is only in Powershell 4.

You can do this tho:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | Select-Object DeviceID, Size, FreeSpace, VolumeName
```

Comment: that does work.. but how do I get the ObjectID ? it looks like \\?\Volume{Guid}\

Comment: like that -- $volumes = get-volume
foreach ($volume in $volumes) {
echo $volume.ObjectId
}

Comment: @ErikMandke You can find the `ObjectID` in `Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume | Select DeviceID`